# How to loop data in different views in ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I have five pages with different state. The first page contains object with the format

```
{
  "good": {
    "good1": "good",
    "good2": "good",
    "good3": "good"
  },
  "bad": {
    "bad1": "bad",
    "bad2": "bad",
    "bad3": "bad"
  },
  "excellent": {
    "excellent1": "excellent",
    "excellent2": "excellent",
    "excellent3": "excellent"
  }
}
```

this object is saved to localstorage.
This is my [codepen](http://codepen.io/surajkhanal/pen/rMXvBO?editors=1001) where i have tried to show what i really want.The scenario is , good1 value is going to be looping through 4 pages and next time redirect to first page with the next value(ie good2 ) and the next value also goes through the same 4 pages and so on. What i have to do to solve this problem? if i am doing wrong with the object structure, what should be the good approach?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you put your data into a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services), then it will be much easier to share it between pages, persist it to local storage and retrieve it.

```
.factory('amazingData',function() {
  var ohYeah = {
    'good':{
      'good1':'good',
      'good2':'good',
      'good3':'good'
    },
    'bad':{
      'bad1':'bad',
      'bad2':'bad',
      'bad3':'bad'
    },
    'excellent':{
      'excellent1':'excellent',
      'excellent2':'excellent',
      'excellent':'excellent'
    }
  };

  return ohYeah;
})
```

Now you can use this service and inject it into your controllers:

```
.controller('homeCtrl',function($scope, amazingData){
  $scope.data=amazingData;
})
.controller('pageCtrl',function($scope, amazingData){
  $scope.data=amazingData;
})
```

The data will be the same for all pages.